# Convert continuous numerical data to discrete numerical data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have  a pandas dataframe `df` with a column having continuous numerical data.

```
   A    
0   1.5   
1   15.0   
2   12.8   
3   23.2  
4   9.6
```

I want to replace the continuous variables with numerical value based on the following rules:

```
0-10=10
10-20=50
20-100=80
```

The final dataframe obtained should be like this:

```
    A    
0   10  
1   50   
2   50  
3   80  
4   10
```

I had tried to use `pandas.cut(df, bins=[0,10,20,100], labels=[10,50,80])` but it returns a Categorical column. I need the output column to be numerical.

Comment: Do you want this inclusive? Or exclusive? i.e., what should `10` be, `10` or `50`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `to_numeric` to your code

```
pd.to_numeric(pd.cut(df['A'], bins=[0,10,20,100], labels=[10,50,80]))
Out[54]: 
0    10
1    50
2    50
3    80
4    10
Name: A, dtype: int64
```